# Unable to find save_without_transactions method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, metaprogramming, ruby-on-rails-2

We are upgrading a gem([graph_mediator](https://github.com/jpartlow/graph_mediator)) which depends on `activerecord 2.3.18`. The gem is adding some custom behaviour before and after saving model.

We came across following methods which are not obsolete in newer versions of Rails:

1. `save_without_transactions`
2. `save_without_transactions!`

In order to make it work with newer version of rails we need to understand these methods. We search for these methods in `Rails 2.3.18` code-base but couldn't find anywhere. However we could find two [methods](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Transactions:save_with_transactions) which are calling these methods but not able to understand the purpose and actual definition of each above methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source we could find how the method is dynamically created via [alias_method_chain](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Module/alias_method_chain).

The `save_without_transaction` is actually [alias](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb#L12-L16) of `save`.